# Moving Smush plugin menu position to media submenu and removing it from main menu

Tags: admin-menu

I have a dislike of plugins that don't tidy themselves away. Smush is a case in point. Ok, it puts itself at the bottom but really, I'd like to have it as a submenu of Media (or perhaps Tools).

```
`add_action('admin_menu', 'move_smush_menu_page');

function move_smush_menu_page()
{
  add_submenu_page('upload.php', 'Smush', 'Smush', 'manage_options', 'smush');
}`
```

Does the trick, makes Smush a submenu but it's still in the parent menu. How do I remove it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out was easy;

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'move_smush_menu_page');

function move_smush_menu_page()
{
  add_submenu_page('upload.php', 'Smush', 'Smush', 'manage_options', 'smush');
  remove_menu_page( 'smush' );
}`
```